# php parsing multiple json arrays

Tags: php, json

i have a json file(below) that contains multiple values, it's abit like this -

```
-makes

   - the make
     - the model
       - year made
       - year made
       - year made
     - the model
       - year made
       - year made

    - the make
      - the model
       - year made
```

I can't figure out how to loop through each "make" one by one to get the model and year, Every way iv'e tried so far just seems to produce the make and nothing else.

the output im looking for would look like this(using the snippet below from the full json file)

```
am general:hummer:1998
am general:hummer:1999
acura:CL:1997
acura:CL:1998
etc..
```

small snippet of the json file im working with -

```
  {
 "makes": [
   {
 "name": "AM General",
 "models": [
   {
     "name": "Hummer",
     "years": [
       {
         "year": 1998
       },
       {
         "year": 1999
       }
     ]
   }
 ]
   },
  {
  "name": "Acura",
  "models": [
    {
     "name": "CL",
     "years": [
       {
         "year": 1997
       },
       {
         "year": 1998
       },
       {
         "year": 1999
       }
     ]
   },
   {
     "name": "ILX",
     "years": [
       {
         "year": 2013
       },
       {
         "year": 2014
       },
       {
         "year": 2015
       }
     ]
   },
   {
     "name": "ILX Hybrid",
     "years": [
       {
         "year": 2014
       }
     ]
   }
   ]
   }
 ] 
 }
```

Comment: You should post the code you have so far.

Comment: Yes, what have you done to get the make? You are probably closer than you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = json_decode($json);    
foreach ($data->makes as $make) {           // assuming you have gotten this far already...        
    foreach ($make->models as $model) {     // just keep going
        foreach ($model->years as $year) {  // deeper
           echo $make->name . ':' . $model->name . ':' . $year->year . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file using `file_get_contents` and just decode it :

```
$file = file_get_contents('path_to_file');
$decoded = json_deconde($file, true); // produces array
```